# Optimisation of view hierarchy in iOS

Tags: ios, optimization

Consider this view hierarchy:

```
    +----------------------------+ 
    |A                           |
    |+--------+   +------------+ |
    ||B       |   |C           | |
    ||        |   |+----------+| |
    |+--------+   ||D         || |
    |             |+----------+| |
    |             +------------+ |
    +----------------------------+
```

If there is an event on the view "D", the systems hit test returns the view 'A'. Then, it calls `pointInside:withEvent:` on B which returns NO. It recursively goes down in the hierarchy of 'C' (because the `pointInside:withEvent:` returned `YES`) to come to a conclusion that the hit event actually happened in 'B'.

Now, it looks like the `pointinside:withEvent` call on the view 'B' is a waste of CPU. What if the view is very complex and if the system futilely calls this on views, doesn't it adversely affect the system performance?

In this light, how can we, as developers, construct our views to increase the response time to events?

Comment: Unless there is a performance issue seen by the user there is no problem. Attempting to optimize performance without a demonstrated need and performance test is "premature optimization", don't do it.

Comment: But ... but ... okay. :(

Comment: The overall issue is spending time optimizing the wrong thing. Performance measurements are the only way to find the areas that need to be optimized, it any.

Comment: Googled around a bit about it. Interesting thought. Thanks!